# Powershell build - compiling SASS

Tags: css, powershell, tfs, sass

I'm hoping to start using SASS in a Visual Studio 2010 project using Web Workbench - but the issue of version control through TFS has me stumped. To avoid overriding someone else's changes I understand that the outputted CSS should be excluded from source control, and that the SCSS should be compiled to CSS server side during the build process. Currently we use a Powershell script for the build, but I can't seem to find any information on how to incorporate SCSS compilation in Powershell. Is there any decent documentation out there on this process?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: VS2010 - updating question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my lack of experience with Powershell/build scripts in general had me overthinking this. I took the following steps:

1) Installed Ruby for Windows from here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/

2) Open Command Prompt -> entered `gem install ruby`

3) Opened PowerGUI Script Editor (already installed, but can be downloaded here: http://software.dell.com/products/powergui-freeware/)

4) Created a function to execute the following: `sass -t compressed "path\sassInput.scss" "path\sassOutput.css"`

And presto. I do want to have a way of doing this for each .scss file in the directory that is not a partial, but this is enough to get me started for now.

UPDATE:
This is what I ended up with for a Powershell script: (note `$dirpath` is set to my project's root directory elsewhere)

```
$stylesheetPath = $dirpath + "App_Themes\"
$files = Get-ChildItem $stylesheetPath -Filter *.scss 
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $file = $files[$i]
    $fileName = $file.BaseName
    $filePath = $file.FullName
    if (-not $fileName.StartsWith("_")) {
        $newFilePath =  "$stylesheetPath$fileName.css"
        sass -t compressed $filePath $newFilePath
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine using a convention that prefix non partial with the '_' character. In this case you run
Get-ChildItem '_*.scss' -Recurse | %{ sass -t compressed $_.FullName "$($_.FullName -replace '\.scss','.css')" }

Comment: Thanks @GiulioVian - I ended up doing something a little different, but you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need a SASS compiler and your mileage may vary. The original compiler is written in Ruby, so, if you want to use that, you have to install Ruby, the SASS gem and invoke `sass` from your Powershell script.
Another option is to use a compatible compiler like [SassC](https://github.com/sass/sassc) or [C6](https://github.com/c9s/c6) which do not need the Ruby runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. U have this one because powershell have restricted executable policy. **U can do next:**
0. Install **node.js, npm,** **node-sass**

1. Run PowerShell as Administrator
2. Chech policy with `Get-ExecutionPolicy`
   *U will see Restricted*
3. See all policies `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`
4. Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
5. Press "Y"

Use node-sass -w ./input.scss ./output.css

Also, U can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Node.JS (https://nodejs.org/download/)
2. Install Ruby for Windows (http://rubyinstaller.org/)
3. run `npm init` in your project directory to create a packages.json file.
4. install grunt `npm install grunt --save-dev` (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
5. install grunt-contrib-sass `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`
6. create an empty `Gruntfile.js` in your project root
7. add the following to your `gruntfile.js`

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {
      // Do grunt-related things in here
   };
   ```
8. follow instructions here to create a grunt-sass task: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
      **Some simple examples are provided near the end of the readme.**
9. run `grunt` from a powershell window in you project root.
10. PROFIT!

this snippet might help when adding this to your automated build script:

```
push-location c:\dev\project
grunt
pop-location
```